# getting endDate=0001-01-01 in recurring event Range from Outlook graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am trying to get a calendar event from Outlook365 using microsoft graph API. In case of recurring event the end date is coming as endDate=0001-01-01.

The same is for all types of recurring events like NoEnd and Numbered. Even when the end date is fixed

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking enough detail to help the community help you.

Answer (score 0):

That's expected behavior. The `endDate` is only relevant on end date ranges, for `noEnd` and `numbered` there is no end date set on the range. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/recurrence-rules#recurrence-ranges